# How to make a Vanilla JS XMLHttpRequest (Wordpress site)

Tags: javascript, php, django, wordpress

I'm new to wordpress and I'm trying to convert a Django project to wordpress.

I have a script.js file that has the XMLHttpRequest

```
function saveInfo() {

    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', '/save/');

    let csrf = get_csrf();
    request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', csrf);
    
    request.onreadystatechange = () => {

        if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status == 200) {
            console.log(JSON.parse(request.responseText))
        }
    
    }

    request.send(JSON.stringify(datos));
 }
```

Then Django takes the data from that request, saves it to a database and send an email message also with that data:

```
def saveToDB(request):
    if request.method == "POST":

        body = request.body.decode('utf-8')
        body = json.loads(body)

        client = Client(
            email=body['email'],
            edad=body['edad'],
        )
        response = client.save()

        subject = 'Nueva suscripción a TuKeto'
        message = 'Email: ' + body['email'] + body['altura']
        sendEmail = EmailMessage(
                subject, message,
                'example@gmail.com',
                ['example@gmail.com'],
                reply_to=[body['email']],
            )
        status = sendEmail.send()

        return HttpResponse("SAVED")
```

I have found examples in jquery but they are incomplete and I don't know how to connect the ajax to the wordpress back end.

An example of how to make this request with vanilla js and the configuration of the wordpress back end would be very useful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, you're asking how to write the PHP equivalent of that python script, you mean?

Comment: Yes, php for wordpress.

Comment: Ok. And where are you stuck with that exactly? What have you researched and tried so far? What went wrong? Stackoverflow isn't a free write-my-code service, we're volunteers, we don't just provide a freelancing service without cosr. However we will _help_ you with a specific issue within _your_ attempt to implement what you need. See also [ask] for more guidance. Thanks.

Comment: P.s. there doesn't need to be any change to the xmlhttprequest side necessarily, that technology will work with any backend

Comment: As written in the description: I don't know how to connect the request to the wordpress back end. I need help with that.

Comment: Use add_action(). e.g. `add_action( 'wp_ajax_MYACTION', 'callback' );`, `add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_MYACTION', 'callback' );`.  See https://cornershopcreative.com/blog/wordpress-ajax-introduction/ and https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins